# How can i align the text centre to the paper?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a thermal printer,the content that is passed is below (vb & c# given for reference):

vb code :

```
printstring = printstring & vbNewLine & "Fax: " & fax1 & vbNewLine
```

c#:

```
printstring = "Fax"+ fax1 ;
```

and i get the desired output :

> Fax : 26594812

The output is not central aligned.Paper size used in printer is : 3 1/8 x 230',

How can i align the text central to the paper ?

[vb or c# code would be helpful ]

Comment: How are you sending the string to the printer?

Comment: as a string given abov

Comment: I mean what's the code for printing. Not what string you are printing.

Comment: have made a printer class and passed :   Dim obj As New PrinterSetup() With {.PrintingMessage = printstring}
        obj.print()

Comment: You need to specify what your printer object looks like and provide some code samples. They're not .net classes.

Comment: Use a ruler to measure how many characters it prints in an inch.  You can then easily calculate how many spaces to insert at the front of the string to get it centered.

Answer (score 0):

if you are drawing the printout with the Graphics class (PrintDocument PrintPage event has e.Graphics), simply workout the co-ordinate:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString("string to print", fntInstance, Brushes.Black, e.PageBounds.Width / 2 - e.Graphics.MeasureString("string to print",fntInstance).Width/2, yCoord)
```

if you are saving everything to a txt file and then printing that using the default windows thermal printer drivers, workout with some testing how many characters fit a line, then do the same thing, using the "string to print".Length / 2

Lets say the max characters that fit in a line are 34...

```
Dim intMax as Integer = 34
stringToPrint = stringToPrint.PadLeft(intMax / 2 - stringToPrint.Length / 2, " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB:

Add An Module To Your Project-

Add The Following Code In Your Project-

```
Public Sub PrintAlignedText(s As String, Alignment As AlignmentConstants)
    Select Case Alignment
    Case vbCenter
        Printer.CurrentX = (Printer.ScaleWidth - Printer.TextWidth(s)) \ 2
    Case vbLeftJustify
        Printer.CurrentX = 0
    Case vbRightJustify
        Printer.CurrentX = Printer.ScaleWidth - Printer.TextWidth(s)
    End Select
    Printer.Print s
End Sub
```

Then Convert:

```
printstring = printstring & vbNewLine & "Fax: " & fax1 & vbNewLine
```

To

```
PrintAlignedText "Centered Text", vbCenter
```

In PrintDocument.

In C#:

Its Easy Just Converted From The VB Code-

Follow All The Steps From The VB Code And The Codes For C# Are Here If You 
Couldn't Convert It-

Code In Module:

```
public void PrintAlignedText(string s, AlignmentConstants Alignment) {
        switch (Alignment) {
            case vbCenter:
                Printer.CurrentX = (Printer.ScaleWidth - Printer.TextWidth(s));
                2;
                break;
            case vbLeftJustify:
                Printer.CurrentX = 0;
                break;
            case vbRightJustify:
                Printer.CurrentX = (Printer.ScaleWidth - Printer.TextWidth(s));
                break;
        }
        Printer.Print;
        s;
    }
```

Code In PrintDocument:

```
PrintAlignedText;
"Centered Text";
,vbCenter;
```

This Will Print It To The Centre!!Try It!!

If You Want Other Alignments Just Replace The vbCentre To vbLeftJustify For Left Align And vbRightJustify For Right Align.